# I cannot change the size of the Windows Form conditionally from Main()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

While i was working on my new windows form project, i just realized that i cannot change the form and everything else in that form property. The code has no error with it but nothing change.

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Form1 a = new Form1();
    Application.Run(a);
    //this is where program happen and at some point in this program i want to
    //change the size of the form
    a.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 40);                                               
}
```

So i just want to change any property of the form,textbox and so on directly and  conditionally in Main(). Thanks you!

Comment: Set the form properties before `Application.Run`. Also since you are using a custom form called `Form1`, you should be able to change the form's size in designer or in `Load` event handler of the `Form1`.

Comment: Have You tried -> this.Invalidate() ?

Answer (score 3):

Your running your application before changing its Size, first change size of form and then do `Application.Run()`

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Form1 formA = new Form1();       //Instantiate form 
    formA.Size = new Size(40, 40);   //Assign size to it
    Application.Run(formA);          //Display the form                                     
}
```

Comment: But i want to change its property conditionally after its running. I cant change anything inside the form like textbox, button. I just can change it in an event inside Form1 class.

Comment: what is mean by after its running. You can add conditions update properties before displaying the form `Application.Run(formA);`. If you want to resize form after it loads then use `_Load` event

Comment: My Problem is not just the size property but everything else, such as changing textbox1.Text in Main(). I cant just close and reopen the form to update the information. The condition that i mention have no relation to any event like Form load or button click.

Comment: @ĐoànLêNhậtNam, I don't think this can be achieved after loading form. We can change any thing any property before form loads but we can not change size of form once it is populated. To reflect these changes we need to reload/reopen that form. This is the only way I can think it for now.

Comment: of course it can be achieved... you can absolutely change the size of the form with `this.Size = new Size(40, 40)` in `Load` event on the form instance.  I don't know what is being discussed here, but it clearly a consideration unrelated to what is being observed and asked on - and answered on.

Comment: @BrettCaswell, I already mentioned changing size of the form in `Load` event, but OP want to change form size once complete `Load` function executes. I answered on OP's first edit. Now I feel like my answer is not helping OP to fix his/her issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing here is that `Application.Run()` is a blocking operation. If you step through your code in the debugger you will notice, that after calling `Application.Run()` the thread does not return (continue onto the resize) until your Form is closed.

That means if you want to change it's size while your Application is running, you have some choices on how to do that:

1. From the Form class itself:

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           //In the constructor
           this.Size = new Size(100, 100);
       }

       //Or in an event
       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) => this.Size = new Size(100, 100);
   }
   ```
2. From another thread
   **Caution** if you go down this road you will have to be very careful when and from where you change properties of any UI element. Please read up on the implications of CrossThreadCalls ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls?view=netframework-4.8 )

   ```
   static class Program
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// The main entry point for the application.
       /// </summary>
       [STAThread]
       static void Main()
       {
           Application.EnableVisualStyles();
           Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

           Form1 frm1 = new Form1();

           //If you really need to go down this road read up on what this is doing
           Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

           new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
           {
               Random rng = new Random();

               while(true)
               {
                   frm1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(rng.Next(50, 1000), rng.Next(50, 1000));

                   Thread.Sleep(2000);
               }
           })).Start();

           Application.Run(frm1);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: "The problem you are facing here is that Application.Run() is a blocking operation. If you step through your code in the debugger you will notice, that after calling Application.Run() the thread does not return (continue onto the resize) until your Form is closed."
is this happen with controls inside the form too? cos i just cant change the property of everything inside it too

Comment: That fact that `Application.Run` is blocking is the natural behaviour of any form. With or without controls. After you enter the `.Run()` method the thread entering will be used to listen and wait for user input. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run?view=netframework-4.8